# ORM search dynamically? Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I've made a model with a field name Car where users can write  a car model, so I want to count the number of each model.
I was looking

```
self.env['car.model'].search_count(['car_model', '=', 'name_of_model'])
```

So I want to count every data that user write but dynamically.

Comment: where do you need this information, compute field? report? and this cannot be done using search_count because you need a group by to calculate this

Comment: Compute field :D

Comment: Compute field on what model ?  Car model or car?